# Observable in HTML is not updating

Tags: html, typescript, nativescript, nfc

I`m working on an app with nfc capabilities. I´m failing at the very start. To demonstrate and to test the Nfc-Tags, I want to have a button, which starts a Ndef Listener. When an tag is detected the Label should change from "Listening... to "Read: TagMessage". This only gets displayed, when I press an other key.

I´m using the demo-app, which comes with the nativescript-nfc plugin, but instead of an xml page, I need html pages. I searched the web for a day now and could not find any working solution.

HTML-Code:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="Available?" (tap)="this.doCheckAvailable()"></Button>
    <Button text="Enabled?" (tap)="this.doCheckEnabled()"></Button>   
    <Button text="Start listening" (tap)="this.doStartNdefListener()"></Button>
    <Button text="Stop listening" (tap)="this.doStopNdefListener()"></Button>   
    <Label text="{{this.lastNdefDiscovered}}" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

TS-Code:

```
export class NFCReaderComponent extends observable.Observable { 
  public lastNdefDiscovered: string = "Press a button...";
  private nfc: Nfc;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: RouterExtensions,
  ) {
    super();
    this.nfc = new Nfc();
  }

  public ngOnInit() {
    application.android.on(
      application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent,
      (args:any) => {args.cancel = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/home'], {
        transition: {
          name: 'slideTop'
        },
        clearHistory: true
      })}
    );
  }

  public doCheckAvailable() {
    this.nfc.available().then((avail) => {
      console.log("Available? " + avail);
      alert("" + avail);
    }, (err) => {
      alert(err);
    });
  }

  public doCheckEnabled() {
    this.nfc.enabled().then((on) => {
      console.log("Enabled? " + on);
      alert("" + on);
    }, (err) => {
      alert(err);
    });
  }

  public doStartNdefListener() {
    this.lastNdefDiscovered= "";
    this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener((data: NfcNdefData) => {
      if (data.message) {
        let tagMessages = [];
        // data.message is an array of records, so:
        data.message.forEach(record => {
          console.log("Read record: " + JSON.stringify(record));
          tagMessages.push(record.payloadAsString);
        });
        this.set("lastNdefDiscovered", "Read: " + tagMessages.join(", "));
      }
    }, {
      stopAfterFirstRead: true,
      scanHint: "Scan a tag, baby!"
    }).then(
      ()=>this.set("lastNdefDiscovered","Listening...")
    ).catch(err => alert(err));
  }

  public doStopNdefListener() {
    this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener(null).then(() => {
      this.set("lastNdefDiscovered", "Stopped listening.");
    }, (err) => {
      alert(err);
    });
  }
```

For xml the code worked with no complaints, can someone tell how to make it happen for html?

Edit (with NgZone):

```
public doStartNdefListener() {
    this.lastNdefDiscovered= "Listening...";
    this._ngZone.runOutsideAngular(()=> {
      this.nfc.setOnNdefDiscoveredListener((data: NfcNdefData) => {
        if (data.message) {
          let tagMessages = [];
          // data.message is an array of records, so:
          data.message.forEach(record => {
            console.log("Read record: " + JSON.stringify(record));
            tagMessages.push(record.payloadAsString);
          }); 
          this.set("lastNdefDiscovered", "Read: " + tagMessages.join(", "));
          this._ngZone.run(()=>console.log("lastNdef updated..."));
        } 
      })
    })
  }
```

With this changes, it works fine.

Comment: Looking at your code I believe you are using NativeScript Angular flavour. `Observable` from `tns-core-modules` was specifically introduced to handle change detections on a NativeScript Core project.

Angular has its own change detection strategies, just updating the variable will update UI (HTML). May be you will just have to run the event listener inside NgZone to make sure it updates.

Comment: I looked up [NgZone](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone), but I can´t figure out, how to use it on my code. Were exactly should I use it?

Comment: I played around with it and it worked! Please confirm, that I used it correctly.

Comment: why are you running it outside angular? thats what you should be trying to avoid

Comment: To be honest, I don´t know, I just interpreted the [NgZone document](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) i found. This is what I came up with and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `this` within the html. The scope of the html file means that you dont need to use the `this` keyword, just reference the variable directly:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button text="Available?" (tap)="doCheckAvailable()"></Button>
    <Button text="Enabled?" (tap)="doCheckEnabled()"></Button>   
    <Button text="Start listening" (tap)="doStartNdefListener()"></Button>
    <Button text="Stop listening" (tap)="doStopNdefListener()"></Button>   
    <Label text="{{lastNdefDiscovered}}" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You were right, it executes well without it, but it did not solve the problem.